# Jump back in Wordpress loop to change something, possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

**Example:**

We got some nice posts that got a link to jump to the next post with scrolling down the page. No reload, new tab or anything just a simple smoothscrolling of the page.

**Problem:**

We are inside a Wordpress Loop that creates some content from the DB and want to generate a link that jumps to the next run-through that will be generated by the Loop. Within the loop we cant predict what will be the next post/product or whatever post-type the loop should go through. So how am I giving the Link the correct anchor link?

**Possible Solutions:**

Maybe we can store the data from each run in an array?
Maybe we should create a second loop that only saves the data?
Maybe I should just use JS to rename that anchors after it finishes...

Comment: Your question should at least include the code for your loop, so we can properly advise where / what the code should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an incremental `id` with the loop index and assign the anchor to the `current index + 1`. A simple example:

```
<?php

global $wp_query;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
  while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    $post_query->the_post();
    $index = $wp_query->current_post + 1;

    ?>
    <div id="my_post_<?php echo $index; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <?php 
       if (($wp_query->current_post +1) <= ($wp_query->post_count)) {
          echo '<a href="#my_post_<?php echo $index + 1; ?>">Next post</a>';   
       }
    ?>   
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This will work, except for the _last post_, which will have a link that goes nowhere....

Comment: You can check if the current post is the last one and don't create the link in that case. See my updated answer.

Comment: Agreed.  I do tend to prefer `<=` as opposed to `!=`, it's a bit safer.